# Octave terminal stops printing out data , but it is there if I push pgdown, or the down arrow

Tags: octave

Any ideas why it would stop outputting visibly, but still have the data it should? I am using basic printf commands in the script. I think it is a terminal issue, it took some work to get it to run on my win7 machine already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pager blocks output. Try "more off" at the beginning of your script